# Ansible multipassword passfile does not decrypt correctly

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I have the following playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - files/test1/.env
    - files/test2/.env
    - files/test3/.env
  roles:
    - role: test1
    - role: test2
    - role: test3
```

All those `.env` files are encrypted using different password using `ansible-vault`. To decrypt them when copied to the remote host, I want to provide the passwords using a passfile. For that, I have a `.passfile` with the following content:

```
pass1
pass2
pass3
```

Each of those passwords are ordered in a way that match the order of `vars_files` in the playbook. When I want to check that decryption happens properly I run `ansible-vault view  files/test1/.env --vault-pass-file .passfile` but I get the following error: `ERROR! Decryption failed (no vault secrets were found that could decrypt) on files/test1/.env for files/test1/.env`

When I remove passwords `pass2` and `pass3` from `.passfile`, then the exact same command works and I can view the contents of the file. Same happens when I execute the playbook. If there's only one password in the `.passfile`, it fails that it cannot decrypt `files/test2/.env` but when I add `pass2` in the `.passfile` then it fails saying it could not decrypt `files/test1/.env`.

How can I make Ansible decrypt all those files that have been encrypted using different passwords by just using one `passfile`? Thanks in advance.

P.S.: the `passfile` was created with `vim`, ensuring there are no extra lines, whitespaces etc... passwords do contain special characters, tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [vault-ids](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vault_guide/vault_using_encrypted_content.html#passing-vault-ids)

1. Separate your passwords in different files for different vault ids, e.g.

   - `.myid1.passfile`

     ```
     pass1
     ```
   - `.myid2.passfile`

     ```
     pass2
     ```
   - `.myid3.passfile`

     ```
     pass3
     ```
2. Reference the vault ids to be used in your configuration.
   *Here I'm using an environment variable but you can pass this information directly on each command line. Check the documentation*

   ```bash
   export ANSIBLE_VAULT_IDENTITY_LIST="myid1@/path/to/.myid1.passfile,\
   myid2@/path/to/.myid2.passfile,\
   myid3@/path/to/.myid3.passfile"
   ```
3. Encrypt your files using the given correct id (decrypt the already encrypted file prior to this).
   *Note: this step is optionnal but decryption will be slower as ansible will have to try each password in order to find a matching one if it does not know the id. See the above doc*

   ```bash
   ansible-vault encrypt --encrypt-vault-id myid1 files/test1/.env
   ansible-vault encrypt --encrypt-vault-id myid2 files/test2/.env
   ansible-vault encrypt --encrypt-vault-id myid3 files/test3/.env
   ```
4. Now use whatever file, in whatever order with whatever playbook. They will be decrypted on the fly using your configured vault ids. You can add as many vault ids you want in your configuration.